# as.ITime error "invalid substring arguments"

Tags: r, function, time, data.table

The function is giving me unexpected results, with an error message.
Look what I found out

```
as.ITime(reff[["Saida"]])
 [1] "05:24:00"


as.ITime(df[,"Saida"])
 [1] "04:30:00"
```

After it, I execute:

```
diff(reff[["Saida"]], df[,"Saida"])
```

> ```
> Error in substring(paste("0", hh, sep = ""), nchar(paste(hh))) : 
> invalid substring arguments
> ```

How can I solve this problem? Any ideas why this error is appearing?

PS:

This is df

```
structure(list(Linha = 307L, Sentido = 1L, Saida = structure(16200L, class = "ITime"), 
Chegada = structure(16740L, class = "ITime"), Catraca = 0L, 
Embarcado = 25L, dia = "sexta", feriado = TRUE, isOL = FALSE, 
antes = TRUE, proximo = TRUE), .Names = c("Linha", "Sentido", 
"Saida", "Chegada", "Catraca", "Embarcado", "dia", "feriado", 
"isOL", "antes", "proximo"), row.names = 747092L, class = "data.frame")
```

This is reff

```
structure(list(Linha = 307L, Sentido = 1L, Saida = structure(19440L, class = "ITime"), 
Chegada = structure(20700L, class = "ITime"), Catraca = 35L, 
Embarcado = 125L, dia = "sexta", feriado = TRUE, isOL = TRUE, 
antes = TRUE, proximo = TRUE), .Names = c("Linha", "Sentido", 
"Saida", "Chegada", "Catraca", "Embarcado", "dia", "feriado", 
"isOL", "antes", "proximo"), row.names = 747094L, class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `difftime` (see `?difftime`) instead of `diff` (see `?diff`):

```
difftime(reff[["Saida"]], df[,"Saida"])
```

> Time difference of 54 mins

`diff` is for creating lags of 1 variable. `difftime` is for taking the difference between 2 time/date variables.

Comment: Maybe instead "diff is for taking the difference between one variable and its own lag". Could also point to `?diff`, `?as.ITime` (which links to ?difftime through ?DateTimeClasses).

Comment: @Frank Added the references to the relevant documentation via `?`. Thanks